# jquery use two .append() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, append

i'm trying to use jquery to append an element to two places, but only the one comes last works(i.e place_2), while the first place doesn't get append.

code:

```
$("#place_1").append(new_line);
$("#place_2").append(new_line);
```

anyone could help?

Comment: is your js console reporting any error? how and where did you defined _newline_?

Comment: hi @F.Calderan. no error in console. new_line is a div container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element has only one place in the DOM tree so the second `append`, in fact, moves the element.

You can use this

```
$("#place_1").append($(new_line_html));
$("#place_2").append($(new_line_html));
```

Or

```
$("#place_1").append(new_line);
$("#place_2").append($(new_line).clone());
```

Comment: You're right, you could extend explaining how `append` simply moves the element and suggest using `.clone` or similar.

Comment: My God... you typed that at the same time as I was editing. Obviously I agree ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think its enough

```
   $("#place_1, #place_2").append(new_line);
```

Comment: @Mario this is easier and faster and don't need cloing